# How do we use nginx to proxy pass the IP server and port to a hostname in that server

Tags: nginx

How do we use nginx to proxy pass the IP server and port to a hostname in that server?

For example, I have a server, 192.168.1.10 and a hostname abc.xyz within that server. I want to forward all traffic for port 8000 to the hostname abc.xyz.

192.168.1.10:8000 -> abc.xyz:8000

It can be TCP/UDP, not HTTP only